# Working solution for AdMob on Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone, admob

I tried 2 possible way to show AdMob ads but none works. First I tried [this](http://admobwp7.codeplex.com/) but I get error in Output window (one line was False, another something with pdb file and so). Then I tried google and found old version of Google Ads SDK for WP7. Now I am getting in Output windows: `An exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary`
So is there working solution for AdMob on Windows Phone 7? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think [Ad Rotator](http://wp7adrotator.codeplex.com/) is a good option, because it still actively maintained and support multiple Ad providers (including AdMob). You can simply put Ad Rotator control in your application Page :

```
<adRotator:AdRotatorControl x:Name="AdRotatorControl" 
xmlns:adRotator="clr-namespace:AdRotator;assembly=AdRotator"
Width="480" Height="80"
    SettingsUrl="http://mydomain.com/myAdSettings.xml"
    DefaultAdType="AdMob"
    DefaultSettingsFileUri="/AppAssemblyName;component/defaultAdSettings.xml"
    AdMobAdUnitId="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    SlidingAdDirection="Left"
    SlidingAdDisplaySeconds="10"
    SlidingAdHiddenSeconds="20"/>
```

Then in page loaded event, call `Invalidate` method to reload ads :

```
void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    AdRotatorControl.Invalidate();
}
```

Note: You have to provide Ads configuration in xml format, the file that refered as defaultAdSettings.xml in above sample. Refer to [Ad Rotator project documentation](http://wp7adrotator.codeplex.com/documentation) for information about the format of the file. Also check tutorial on getting started to use Ad Rotator [here](http://darkgenesis.zenithmoon.com/would-you-like-ads-with-thatintro-to-adrotator-for-wp7/), written by the creator of Ad Rotator.

Actually I haven't tried this, but it looks promising.